# Can we use two brace expansions together?

Tags: bash, shell

For example, I want to rename a file `abc` to `bd`.

Why do the two brace expansions seem not to work?

Consider the following example.

```
$ touch abc
$ mv {a,}b{c,d}
mv: target `bd' is not a directory
```

How shall I make brace expansion work?

Answer (score 4):

Two brace expansions do work, they just don't work the way you want them to:

```
$ touch abc
$ mv {a,}b{c,d}
mv: target `bd' is not a directory
$ echo mv {a,}b{c,d}
mv abc abd bc bd
```

They are expanded separately - effectively the first one is expanded, leaving you with `mv ab{c,d} b{c,d}` and then the second is expanded, leaving you with `mv abc abd bc bd`.

Comment: how can I use brace expansions to do what I want?

Comment: @Tim, a brace expansion will produce $number_of_commas+1 words, and using multiple brace expansions within a single argument will create the cross product.  Since you want to only have 2 arguments at the end, you can only use one comma, which means that the only way to do it with brace expansion would be `mv {abc,bd}` - but that's harder to type and less obvious than just `mv abc bd`.

Comment: in case `a`, `b` and `c` are replaced with long strings, that is why I try to use brace expansion. Or shall I use brace expansion one each time and multiple times?

Comment: Without having more details it's hard to say, but the obvious solution would just be to use variables.  `a=foo b=bar c=baz d=bang; mv $a$b$c $b$d`

Comment: @Tim, given that you can't really do what you want to do with brace expansion, I'd ask a new question that explains exactly what you're trying to do, with a more detailed example, and ask for solutions to that problem.